# How to build a nested MongoDB query in java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to translate a working Mongo Shell query to java, but it seems like I have ran into a wall. I am using the mongo-java-driver:3.9.1. The shell query looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('xyz').find({source_id: ObjectId("abc"), timestamp: {
    $gte : ISODate("2019-04-05 18:24:00.000Z"),
    $lt: ISODate("2019-04-05 18:30:00.000Z")
    }
  })
```

The query includes two criterias: a matching source_id and timestamps between the two given dates.

My Java query looks like this (startDate and endDate are formatted Dates):

```
FindIterable<Document> cursor = collection.find(and(eq("source_id", new ObjectId("abc"))), and(gte("timestamp", startDate), lt("timestamp", endDate)));
```

Intellij gives me the message: "Cannot resolve method 'find(org.bson.conversions.Bson, org.bson.conversions.Bson)". Is this a logical error, or is building a filter like that not possible?

Comment: Are you using `spring-data-mongodb` repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one `and`:

```
FindIterable<Document> cursor = collection.find(and(and(eq("source_id", new ObjectId("abc"))), and(gte("timestamp", startDate), lt("timestamp", endDate))));
```

The general idea is: think of every `{` as an encompassing `and` statement.